# Cannot extend generic type where placeholder is another generic type

Tags: swift

I want to extend an `Array` where the `Element` is a nested class of a generic type:

```
class GenericType<T: ExpressibleByInt> {
    class NestedClass {
    }
}

extension Array where Element == GenericType.NestedClass {   // Fails: Reference to generic type 'GenericType' requires arguments in <...>.
...
}
```

Is there a syntax for expressing an extension for a generic where the generic's element is the nested class of another generic?

Comment: @LeoDabus The element is not a generic structure. It is the nested class of a generic structure.

Comment: @LeoDabus What do you see duplicated between my question and that one?

Comment: @LeoDabus This is not constraining an extension element to a generic type. It is constraining an extension element to a **nested class of a generic type**.

Comment: @LeoDabus First of all there is no solution to the problems proposed in either question, only workarounds. Second, you said this **question** is a possible duplicate of another **question**, and your argument is that the **solutions** are the same. Similar solutions is not a justification for claiming similar questions.

Comment: @LeoDabus It does matter because that is the basis as to why the questions are not duplicates. You keep talking about the solution as if there is some contention on how this problem needs to be worked around. There is not. The contention is that you pointed out that this is a possible duplicate when there is no duplication. End of story.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to express this at the extension level. You have to do it at the method/subscript/initializer level. (So you're out of luck for properties, unfortunately.)

```swift
extension Array {
  func ƒ<T>() where Element == GenericType<T>.NestedClass { }

  subscript<T>(_: T.Type = T.self) -> Void
  where Element == GenericType<T>.NestedClass {
    get { }
  }

  init?<T>() where Element == GenericType<T>.NestedClass {
    nil
  }
}
```